# Need to add textboxes to gridview cell on Edit select

Tags: vb.net, gridview

I could really use some help on this. I have been searching for a solution on the web but haven't been able to find much help.

I need to add textboxes to a gridview edit cell, based on the number of rows of text in one of the cells. I have coded the capture of the number of textboxes I need to add.

But I am not sure which Gridview event to add the code, when going into edit mode, to run the loop that will insert additional Textboxes in a specific column of the row selected to edit.

The user sees colA that has text with line vbCRLF's embedded say:

"This is sample text."

"Line2"

"Line3"

My code reads three Carriage Return, Line feeds. So when the user goes into Edit mode I want to provide one text box for each line or more accurately, add two more as one will already exist.

Thanks for any possible help on this.

Regards,

UPDATE: Here is the solution......

```
Private Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound 
If (e.Row.RowState And DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0 Then 
  Dim ph As PlaceHolder = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("PlaceHolder1"), PlaceHolder) 
  For I = 1 To BoxesNeeded 
    Dim txtB As New TextBox 
    txtB.ID = "txtBEdit" & I.ToString("D2") 
    ph.Controls.Add(txtB) 
    Dim litCtrl As New Literal 
    litCtrl.ID = "litCtrl" & I.ToString("D2") 
    litCtrl.Text = "<br />" 
    ph.Controls.Add(litCtrl) 
  Next I 
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: You should post your solution as the answer and accept it.

Comment: Matt, You can not accept answers to your own questions.

Comment: You could up vote it for me though, I can't even do that, it did solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution....

```
Private Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound 
    If (e.Row.RowState And DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0 Then 
        Dim ph As PlaceHolder = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("PlaceHolder1"), PlaceHolder) 
        For I = 1 To BoxesNeeded 
            Dim txtB As New TextBox 
            txtB.ID = "txtBEdit" & I.ToString("D2") 
            ph.Controls.Add(txtB) 
            Dim litCtrl As New Literal 
            litCtrl.ID = "litCtrl" & I.ToString("D2") 
            litCtrl.Text = "<br />" 
            ph.Controls.Add(litCtrl) 
        Next I 
    End If
```

thanks,